# Relative path in MergedDictionary (Silverlight on Windows Phone): .. doesn't work

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, resources

I have a project with folder structure

```
Root
+ App.xaml
+ MainPage.xaml
+ UI
  + Controls
    + Control1.xaml
    + Control2.xaml
  + Styles
    + Colors.xaml
  + Page1.xaml
  + Page2.xaml
```

I'm trying to reference Colors.xaml from Control1.xaml with following markup:

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../Styles/Colors.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    [...]
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

I get error

> An error occurred while finding the resource dictionary "../Styles/Colors.xaml".

If I try `<ResourceDictionary Source="/UI/Styles/Colors.xaml"/>`, I get

> Project does not support paths relative to the root application directory. Remove the leading '/' qualifier from the '/UI/Styles/Colors.xaml' path to correct the problem.

From what people in Internet say, my first approach should work. I guess it's Windows Phone specific issue, but how do I get around it?

EDIT: one workaround I found is `Source="/MyApp.Phone;component/UI/Styles/Colors.xaml"`,
`MyApp.Phone` being project name

Comment: Removing the leading '/' qualifier from the '/UI/Styles/Colors.xaml' don't solve your problem?

Comment: It doesn't. Removing leading / turns this URL into relative to /UI/Controls
Exception is Failed to assign to property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source'

Comment: And if you just remove the two dots?  ..

Comment: If I remove them, I get error of approach #2, about leading '/'

Comment: I think you should stick to calling /<Assembly Name>;component. That is the most reliable way to make this work in Silverlight 4.